# Point decompression on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, compression

I'm programming an elliptic curve cryptosystem and I'm having difficulty with decompressing points. The following information is from my project specification as to my understanding:

Given a point $x$ and $y$, we can compress its representation since for every $x$ on the curve, there are two $y$s; one even and one odd. Therefore, we can express the point as $x$ concatenated with a bit $y'$, thus representing the point in half the bits. To do this, we calculate $y' := y \bmod 2$ to detect if $y$ it is even or odd and add this remainder to the $x$ value which has been left-shifted by one bit (one can think of this representation as $2x + y'$). I understand completely why we do this, in fact it's pretty ingenious. My problem is with decompressing the point which apparently involves square roots in a finite field.

Since the equation of the elliptic curve is $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are parameters of the curve, we apparently need to compute square roots to uncover $y$. I know how to recover $x$ from the compressed representation; just subtract $1$ if it is odd and divide by $2$ and that's the $x$ coordinate. My specification noted the formula: If $p$ is prime and congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, then finding square roots of an element $z\in\mathbb F_p$ is easy. $z^{(p+1)/4}$ is one root and the other is its negative. This confuses me: Why is this a square root and how do I implement this computation?

Answer (score 9):

Let $x\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ be the point's first coordinate, and define
$z := x^3+ax+b$. We know that there exists a square root $y\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ of $z$, i.e. $y^2=z$.
Let's assume we have already found such an $y$. Since the order of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\ast$ is $p-1$, [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) implies $y^p=y\text,$ hence
$$\left(z^{(p+1)/4}\right)^2=\left((y^2)^{(p+1)/4}\right)^2=\left(y^{(p+1)/2}\right)^2=y^{p+1}=y^2=z\text,$$
which shows that $z^{(p+1)/4}$ is a square root of $z$. The possible second coordinates for the uncompressed point are thus $z^{(p+1)/4}$ and $-z^{(p+1)/4}$, and you can select the right one using the "sign" bit from the compressed representation.

Comment: What is the significance of the 'sign' bit? Could you explain to me why the first bit of the y denotes whether the point is negative or not, and could you explain why there is one odd y and one even y for every x (why can't they both be even and vice versa)? Thanks

Comment: This answer assumes $p\bmod 4=3$. The "sign bit" is conventionally $(y\bmod p)\bmod2$, encoded as byte `02`or `03`. See [sec1v2 section 2.3.4](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.4), subcase 2, and within this 2.4.1

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with this as well when I was learning about ECC. I have no idea if this is the technically correct way to do it, but it works in my program... Well, I know for a fact it works with secp256k1, secp384r1, and secp511r1 at least.

```
i = (first byte of compressed point) mod 2
y2 = ((x ^ 3 mod p) + a*x + b) mod p
y_ = (y2 ^ ((p+1)/4)) mod p

if i is odd: y = p-y_
else y = y_
```

Comment: The test is incorrect; it could be corrected to `if i+p is odd`. Also, it's useful to check that `y^2 mod p` equals `y2`, which catches a possibly invalid `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Shanks-Tonelli algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) about modular square root.

On binary curves $y^2 +  x y - (x^3 + bx^2 + b) = 0$, you can rewrite it as $y^2 + Ay + B = 0$, you need to solve a quadratic equation in $F(2^m)$.

( [http://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~koclab/teaching/ccs130h/projects/03-ecc-protocols/Julio_Slides.pdf](http://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Ekoclab/teaching/ccs130h/projects/03-ecc-protocols/Julio_Slides.pdf) )

Computation complexity is about the same (prime curves and binary curves), with a slight advantage to binary implementations where squaring and modular square root are really really fast.

Comment: Shanks-Tonelli is the general answer for prime curves; however most elliptic curves have $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, and in this case, the problem can be simplified: to compute the square root of $n$, you just compute $n^{(p+1)/4}$ (and check that that value squared gives you $n$; this last bit catches values of $n$ that don't have a square root)