# Roots in modulo field

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic

I have a point $(X,Y)$ on an elliptical curve $E(a,b)$ where $a=-3$ and $B$ is a large number that is in hexadecimal from -51BD. To compress this point oficially in a program, we know that every $X$ on the curve has two $Y$'s, one even and one odd. Therefore, we only need to store whether the corresponding $Y$ point we are storing is even or odd. So to store the point $(X,Y)$ now, we shift $X$ ridding of its most significant bit and add $1$ if the $Y$ point is odd. Therefore, one can think of the compressed point being $2 \cdot X+B$ ($B$ is the bit we added to tell if $Y$ was odd or even) since the multiplication by $2$ is implied because of the shift. I understand this completely. It's recovering the original point that has me confused.

Since a point on the curve is given by the equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, we can find square roots officially in $\mathrm{GF}(p)$. The following from my spec is what confuses me.

If $p$ is prime and congruent to $3$ mod $4$, one of its square roots is $z^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$ and the other is $p-z^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$. How would I solve this? What is $z$?

For example, I know how to extract the $x$ point so let's say I simplify the right side of the equation to be $7$ and $p$ is $11$. Would I be trying to solve for the square root that's equal to $7$ mod $11$?

Comment: This question is related to this [recent one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20627/point-decompression-on-a-elliptical-curve). It is maybe a homework?

Comment: yup, that one is not answered so I figured I'd write a nicer looking question and hope for an answer.

Comment: Corrected: If $p$ is prime and congruent to $3$ mod $4$, and $z$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, then one of $z$'s square roots mod $p$ is $z^{(p+1)/4}$ and the other is $p-z^{(p+1)/4}$.

Comment: so I've made some progress in understanding this since I'm going to get a whole number exponent. What is z? Is z what i calculate the right side of the equation to be? Determing z is confusing me. Could you give me an example where like P is 11 and A is 1 and B is 6. Once I see how to solve it than I know i can program it. I have algorithms implemented like the repeated square

Comment: $z$ is whatever you want to compute the square root of. Of course, you must first be sure that it is a quadratic residue.

Comment: So let's say i calculate the right side of the equation to be equivalent to 10. Than I'm trying to solve y^2 = 10 mod 11. Since 11 is congruent to 3 mod 4. Than the square roots of y are y^3 and p-y^3. How would I solve for y? Is there a better way than guess and check since in the actual program, the prime p is pretty large

Comment: or should the the answers of y be equivalent to 10^3 mod 11

Comment: To avoid confusion, if I'm left with y^2 is congruent to 3 mod 11, is 3 the z to find the roots?

Comment: 10 is not a quadratic residue mod 11, so it has no square root mod 11.

Comment: okay i think i got it now, z would be whatever my right side of the equation mod p is.

Comment: Right, I guess I'm going to write up an answer...

Answer (score 5):

You want to find a point $(X,Y)$ on an elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ knowing only $X$ and a single bit indicating whether $Y$ is even or odd. To find $Y$, you use the relation defining the curve: you know that $Y^2 = X^3 + aX + b$ since the point is on the curve. So you compute $X^3 + aX + b$ using your value of $X$ and the public parameters $a, b$, and you want to find values of $Y$ such that $Y^2$ is equal to that value.

If the modulus $p$ is congruent to $3$ mod $4$, that's very easy to do: for any $z$, the square roots of $z$, if they exist, are $\pm z^{(p+1)/4} \bmod{p}$. Indeed, suppose $z$ has a square root, say $a$. Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$, and let $a = g^x$. Then $z = (g^x)^2 = g^{2x}$. In turn,

$$(z^{(p+1)/4})^2 = z^{(p+1)/2} = (g^{2x})^{(p+1)/2} = (g^x)^{p+1} = (g^x)^{p-1}g^{2x} = g^{2x} = z$$

which shows that $z^{(p+1)/4}$ is indeed a square root of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

> If p is prime and congruent to 3 mod 4, one of its square roots is z(p+1)/4modp and the other is p−z(p+1)/4modp. How would I solve this? What is z?

If the elliptic curve equation is given by $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, to find the value of $y$ you would need to find the square root of the right hand side of the equation, meaning that $z = x^3 + ax + b$ in this case.

You would solve this by substituting in all of the parameters that you know -- $p$ is an elliptic curve parameter (the order of the Galois field $GF(p)$), and you have $a$ and $b$ as defined in your question.

> Would I be trying to solve for the square root that's equal to 7 mod 11?

It's a little more accurate to say that you would be trying to solve for $y$ (or the two values of $y$) such that $y^2 \equiv 7 \bmod 11$.