# Can you recover $y$ if you have $x$ in Pedersen hash?

Tags: hash

(this might be a silly question)

Pedersen hash works in the following way: $(x, y) = kG$ where $k$ is the pre-image and $(x, y)$ is the resulting hash.

Say we hide part of the hash to preserve privacy. Can an attacker derive $y$ if they only know $x$ given that they don't know the pre-image?

In other words, by knowing $x$ can an attacker find $y$ even if they don't know $y$ nor $k$.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Roots in modulo field](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20636/18298) and [Is it possible to compute the y-coordinate of a point on SECP256K1, given only the x-coordinate](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82027/18298)

Comment: Thank you. Indeed you only need to know if $y$ is odd or even to fully recover the $(x, y)$ pair.

Comment: For future searches, put this into your list [SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to narrow $y$ down to one of two possible values.

The numbers $x$ and $y$ represent the co-ordinates of an [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) over a finite field. Depending on the curve selected for your commitment scheme, there will be an equation for the curve and usually a prime $p$ over which the curve is defined.

For example the widely used NIST P256 curve is defined using the prime $p=2^{256}-2^{224}+2^{192}+2^{96}-1$ and the equation
$$y^2\equiv x^3-3x+b\pmod p$$
where $b$ is the number 0x5ac635d8aa3a93e7b3ebbd55769886bc651d06b0cc53b0f63bce3c3e27d2604b.

Given $x$ we can compute $y^2\mod p$ using this equation. There should then be two possible square roots which we can compute as
$$y=\pm (x^3-3x+b)^{(p+1)/4}\mod p.$$

Another common scheme uses the Ed25519 curve which uses the prime $p=2^{255}-19$ and the equation
$$-x^2+y^2=1-\frac{121665}{121666}x^2y^2\pmod p.$$

Again, given $x$ one can rearrange and solve for two possible $y$ values (though the computation is not as short to write down as the one above).

In both cases, each of the 2 $y$ values is possible and there is no way to determine which is correct without further information.

Comment: Wow. This is really helpful, thank you. Looks like the $y$ value really only adds 1 bit of entropy to the hash.